# Solving a double absolute inequality

Tags: inequality

|x-1| < |2x+3|

I'm just wondering if somebody could verify that I've done this right.

Case 1: x < -3/2

-(x-1) < -(2x+3)

x < -4 [Valid because it satisfies the case]

Case 2: -3/2 <= x < 1

-(x-1) < 2x+3

x > -2/3 [Valid because it satisfies the case]

Case 3: x >= 1

x-1 < 2x+3

x > -4 [Not valid because it doesn't satisfy x >= 1]

Therefore {x < -4} U {x > -2/3}

Comment: Another way could be taking square on both sides of the inequality.

Comment: Would you mind using [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr)?

Answer (score 1):

your 8th and 11th lines are wrong. You should combine the constraints on X, which you imposed, with the results you got.

8th line should be $-2/3 < x < 1$

11th line should be $x \geq 1$

Now, when you combine all your results, you get the answer, which matches yours.

---

Another way to help yourself is to simply plot the functions on the XY-plane.

Comment: Are you saying I should run x > -2/3 through all 3 constraints, and if it passes then I keep it as a solution?

Comment: edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Assuming $$x\geq 1$$ we gert $$x-1<2x+3$$
In the next case we have $$-\frac{3}{2}\le x<1$$ and we get $$-x+1<2x+3$$
And for $$x<-\frac{3}{2}$$ we get $$-x+1<-2x-3$$

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. So my solution is correct (including discarding the x > -4)?

Comment: The solution is given by $$x<-4$$ or $$x>-\frac{2}{3}$$